# Apply multiple filters to the aggregate function of a field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to compute with multiple filters applied to the aggregate function in a field calculator, but it is not working. Is this not possible in the field calculator?
Here are the formulas and errors for the Field Calculator.

I assume an expression that counts the number of layer B geometries around the point geometry of the reference layer that satisfy the three conditions.

```
 array_length( 
  overlay_nearest('layer_B',
   $id ,
   limit:=-1,
   filter:= "field_b1"=1 & "field_b2">0 & "field_b2"<20,
   max_distance:=30
   )
   )
```

```
syntax error, unexpected Unknown_CHARACTER, expecting COMMA or ')'
syntax error, unexpected Unknown_CHARACTER, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected COMMA, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `eval()` function to evaluate an expression string like so:

```
array_length( 
  overlay_nearest('layer_B',
    $id,
    limit:=-1,
    filter:=eval('"field_b1"=1 and "field_b2">0 and "field_b2"<20'),
    max_distance:=30
  )
)
```

Note the use of `and` rather than `&`, also.

###### From the help pane of the field calculator

> ###### function eval
>
> Evaluates an expression which is passed in a string. Useful to expand dynamic parameters passed as context variables or fields.
>
> ###### Syntax
>
> **eval**(expression)
>
> ###### Arguments
>
> *expression* an expression string
>
> ###### Examples
>
> eval(''nice'') → 'nice'
> eval(@expression_var) → [whatever the result of evaluating @expression_var might be…]

Comment: Thank you very much.
I got the same output with and without eval().

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, it helped me learn about eval()!